# symfony2 + compass: about using url('image')

Tags: symfony

I have added these lines to my config.yml:

```
assetic.filter.compass.images_dir:%kernel.root_dir%/../web/bundles/canalonesbastimarfrontend/images   
assetic.filter.compass.generated_images_path: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images
```

And I have a scss file with this content:

```
background: url('/00.png') repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

and a file called `00.png` in `web/bundles/canalonesbastimarfrontend/images/00.png`, but I get 404 for that image. I have followed this [tuto](http://alexandre-salome.fr/blog/Sass-Compass-Assetic-In-Ten-Minutes).

If I put the image file inside `web/images` it works corretly, but Im not interested in that, but in keeping the images in `web/bundles/canalonesbastimarfrontend/images/` since the images of the bundle are placed there.

Comment: use `image-url` in your scss and path without leading slash `background: image-url('00.png') repeat scrol 0 0 transparent`

Comment: @waldek_c thanks, but it does not work

Comment: ok, in config.yml add another parameter `assetic.filter.compass.http_path: /bundles/canalonesbastimarfrontend` and use `image-url` in scss :)